# Difference between "knowledge" and "know-how"

Tags: differences, nouns

Is there any difference between these two?

Do (suppose) *technical knowledge* and *technical know-how* convey different meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Knowledge" is the acquaintance with the facts and information. You know it, *in your head*.

"Know-how" is the knowledge of how to *do something*. In other words, "know-how" is the ability to perform a task or action.

Comment: I agree: in other words theory and practice.

Comment: In some (but definitely not all) areas know-how also requires knowledge.

Comment: I would rather say: knowledge is plain theory and know-how is the theory you need to do something in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the terms *knowledge* and *know-how* are very similar.  The only two small differences I can think of are perhaps that *know-how* is a bit less formal than *knowledge*, and that *know-how* may place a little more emphasis on knowledge of how to do something practical/physical, as opposed to *knowledge* being potentially more abstract.  That said, you can certainly have *knowledge* about how to do practical/physical tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Different perspectives :

*Conceptual :*

- ***Knowledge*** allows you to explain the thing
- ***Know-how*** allows you to do / make the thing

*Cognitive :*

- ***Knowlegde*** is what your head knows. It is mental, conceptual.
- ***Know-how*** is what your "body" knows. (Even if the body is steered by the brain) It is procedural.